Laravel Weak Encoding for Tokens
The pentest result on our website gave information as follows. But I don't understand what to do about it. token is already happening automatically by laravel, what should I do?
Application tokens (XSRF and Admin) uses insecure Base 64 encoding which can be decoded.
Use appropriate cryptographic algorithms designed for security purposes, such as AES, RSA or SHA256.
Attack Scenario:
In a weak encoding for tokens scenario, an attacker intercepts tokens transmitted between a client and a
server. Using knowledge of the encoding method, they decode the tokens, gaining unauthorized access
to sensitive data or functionality. (There is a possibility of data breach due to this vulnerability)
enter image description here
I couldn't find any results

This is a false positive that can be safely ignored.
If you base64 decode the value, you'll get something like this:
{"iv":"flrOf9...FBZUA==","value":"4QSGL576...2f951b","mac":"f4c1a47e07ec...e607ddb9eea","tag":""}

The value is encrypted with your APP_KEY as the secret (typically using AES-256), the iv is the encryption initialization vector, and the mac signature prevents any attempts at modification of the data.
(This is all handled by the EncryptCookies middleware that's included by default in any Laravel install.)
It's base64 encoded because you can store binary data in a Laravel cookie, not for any security purpose.
